# How to configure O365 for Business Premium suite to automatically login or prompt for credentials from home computer?

Tags: microsoft-office, login, credentials

We are a small company, and I purchase my own O365 subscription as I want to have the additional functionality.  Unfortunately, I am the only technically inclined individual in the office to the degree that I handle nearly all the IT work.  I say this without any hubris; rather, I feel very ill-equipped and uneducated, but among my colleagues and the administration are those who *still* prefer fax over e-mail or practice double-entry book-keeping despite our recent implementation of an ERM system.

With that in mind, you can imagine what kind of expressions I receive whenever I talk about IFTTT, IoT, Flow, SharePoint, etc.  In other words, any modernization that takes place is wholly developed and implemented by myself (armed with Google and SU).  Because of this, I often need to take my work home to finish off-the-clock, which brings about additional headaches.

For one thing, work documents often are not syncing properly to the cloud for some reason.  When taking a better look at the O365 settings, I'm currently inferring that the cause for this is the incorrect login credentials being utilized by **both** workstations.  At the office, O365 seems to default to our domain user identity as the login despite the fact that it doesn't even exist as far as Office365 should be concerned; due to an inability to consolidate between our domain hosting with our e-mail Exchange service (hosted by a 3rd party apart from our on-site server or Microsoft's own servers), I've had to assign licensing using a `domainname.onmicrosoft.com` basis, which is technically not fully configured (meant to be temporary); yet even after logging in, I'll notice randomly that the O365 applications will have switched back over to the local user identity and I'll have to manually log out and back in to the correct account.

From home, the same issue is occurring, except through my personal account.  I have my work account defined and added to the system settings -- only the `.onmicrosoft` variant at this time -- yet O365 insists on defaulting to my personal account, which does not even have any active O365 subscription licensed to it.  How can I alter this behavior to either 1) automatically and persistently default to access credentials I define myself (needs to contend with 2FA as well), or 2) prompt for credentials on each...well, whatever triggers the active session to expire and default back currently?  I'd consider some sort of delegate access setup if it'd grant full access permissions equivalent to my actual license, except based on my run-ins with external user permissions thusfar I'm going to hazard a guess and say it wouldn't be possible.

As I only have some superficial knowledge in AHK (and some VB6 & python from a *decade* ago), any additional verbosity would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suspect you can do this with the [Office deployment tool](https://config.office.com/).  Have you tried using it?

Comment: No, in fact the only deployment "tool" that was offered to me consisted of modifying some .xml values (manually through Notepad++) and then running it through `cmd.exe` with some additional arguments.  Thanks for the link, I'll take a better look when I get to the office!